# Redirect after logout module doesn't redirect with link

Tags: 7, redirection, users

I'm working with the [redirect after logout module](https://drupal.org/project/redirect_after_logout) to redirect the user to the login page after he logs out.

Now I have a link in my main menu with route `user/logout`. And my module `redirect after logout` is configured to redirect to `user/login`.

But when I click on the link I'm not redirected to user/login but I'm being send to the 'front-page' (I am logged out). And when I surf to `mylink.com/user/logout` I am being redirected to user/login. Why doesn't this work with the link?

Comment: your main menu is built by Drupal or custom menu?

Comment: are you using anything else like logintoboggan that might be intercepting the redirect?

Comment: No, I'm not using another module that could interfere with the redirect module.